# Calling a stored proc from perl

Tags: perl, plsql

I am running this subroutine from the main script.

```
print "parameter passed: $_[0]";
my $connect_string = 'test/test@testdb';
my $sqlplus_settings = '';
my $task = '';
my $result = qx { sqlplus $connect_string << EOF
$sqlplus_settings exec {pkgname.procedure($_[0], 'abc',$task);
#exit;
EOF
```

When it is getting called from the main script `{sub($var)}`, it is printing the first line with the input parameter. But the procedure is not getting executed.

Comment: There is no _subroutine_ in your code.

Comment: Use [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI) to talk to a database.

Comment: Add `use strict` and `use warnings`. But even without, it should tell you about the syntax errors with your HEREDOC.

Comment: I have pasted the code of the subroutine here. I am calling the same from main with the below syntax.                                                                                 init($scr)                                                                                                                      where $scr is being passed from the main script.                                                Also I am getting a warning : warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')

Comment: You should remove preceeding spaces before EOF i.e change to `<<  EOF` to `<<EOF`.

Comment: I have rephrased my code in the following way.                                                      
my $dbh =  DBI->connect('dbi:Oracle:', 'test/test@testdb');
eval {
my $proc =
              $dbh->prepare(
                q{BEGIN} . " MIG_STATUS_AUDIT.MIG_INIT_SINGLE_SCRIPT ($var, $scr, $task) ".q{;END;} );
$proc->execute;
};                                                                                                                        but now getting the error- "Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:". Am I missing something silly here?

Comment: the parameters used in my previous comment are given below.  my $task = '';  
my $scr = 'Migstart.pl';  
my $var = $_[0];  
my $script = " MIG_STATUS_AUDIT.MIG_INIT_SINGLE_SCRIPT ($var, $scr, $task) ";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by user @choroba in the comments above, the best way IMHO is to use Perl's DBI module.

Here is an example of calling your stored procedure that would work with Oracle:

```
$dbh->do("BEGIN your_procedure; END;");
```

And here is a link to help you get started with the DBI module:

[Perl DBI](http://dbi.perl.org/)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I was able to call the stored proc with the use of DBI. I was just missing few QUOTES in the last code snippet I posted here. Thanks again.

Comment: @Gourab Sengupta - glad we could help.  Can I get an upvote for this answer, please?  Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

for me works this solution good:

```
my $execute=q~BEGIN your_procedure; END~;
my $sth= $dbh->prepare($execute);
   $sth->execute()
```